# pandas update dataframe only when all similar values are valid

Tags: python, pandas

I've written this simplified example to explain what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
import pytest

def enable_rows(df, row, myrange):
    # Need to modify this
    df.loc[row + myrange:, 'enabled'] = True
    df.loc[:row - myrange, 'enabled'] = True

def starting_df():
    # just re-creates the initial dataframe to check on values
    distance = {1: (100.0, 'a', False),
                2: (100.0, 'a', False),
                3: (100.0, 'a', False),
                4: (700.0, 'b', False),
                5: (700.0, 'b', False),
                6: (900.0, 'c', False)}

    return pd.DataFrame(data=list(distance.values()), index=list(
        distance.keys()), columns=['distance', 'letter', 'enabled'])

def test_enable(center_row, myrange):
    # convenience function to eye-candy the executions.
    df = starting_df()
    enable_rows(df, center_row, myrange)
    print(df)

    # assertions
    enabled = df.loc[df.enabled]
    if not ((len(enabled) == 3) and
            (len(enabled.loc[df.distance == 100.0]) == 0) and
            (len(enabled.loc[df.distance > 100.0]) == 3)):
        print("wrong result")

test_enable(1, 2)
test_enable(2, 1)
```

The distance dataframe has several contingent rows having the same `distance` and `letter` columns. initially they are all `enabled == False`

I need to set some of them `enabled == True` based on their `row` index and a `range` value, so that all rows with a `range` distance from the one with index `row` will be enabled (and this I managed to get in my `enable_rows` function).

Additionally I need that if one `distance` value wouldn't have all its rows enabled then none should be enabled.

both examples in the code above would have some of the `distance == 100.0` rows still not enabled, so none of the 100.0 should be enabled.

They expect a resulting dataframe as :

```
   distance letter  enabled
1     100.0      a    False
2     100.0      a    False
3     100.0      a    False
4     700.0      b     True
5     700.0      b     True
6     900.0      c     True
```

but the actual output of the program is:

```
   distance letter  enabled
1     100.0      a    False
2     100.0      a    False
3     100.0      a     True
4     700.0      b     True
5     700.0      b     True
6     900.0      c     True
wrong result
   distance letter  enabled
1     100.0      a     True
2     100.0      a    False
3     100.0      a     True
4     700.0      b     True
5     700.0      b     True
6     900.0      c     True
wrong result
```

how could I update `enable_rows` to obtain that?

Comment: there was an error in the example, in there I would have expected also the `700.0` values to be disabled.

Comment: After enabling create a dataframe with only disabled values by putting a filter on enabled, after removing duplicates join this dataframe with your final dataframe on distance and letter, if they find a match in right dataframe update their values as `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `groupby` `'distances'` and `transform` the result if all the `enabled` values are not `True`. You can do this with:

```
df['enabled'] = df.groupby('distance')['enabled'].transform(lambda x: all(x)==True)
```

Which you can use here

```
def enable_rows(df, row, myrange):
    # Need to modify this
    df.loc[row + myrange:, 'enabled'] = True
    df.loc[:row - myrange, 'enabled'] = True
    df['enabled'] = df.groupby('distance')['enabled'].transform(lambda x: all(x)==True)
```